# How to take MAX from column values in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where I need to take max value from different columns from a table in sparksql.

Below is a sample table -

[image]

I want to take the max of values from columns a, b and c without using the union clause.

Below is the SL query I executed -

```
SELECT (
SELECT MAX(myval) 
  FROM (VALUES (a),(b),(c)) AS temp(myval)
) AS MaxOfColumns
FROM
table
```

But this is throwing an error - "cannot evaluate expression outer() in inline table definition; line 3 pos 16"

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: ... and you have only a single row in your table?

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[array_max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_max)

```
with t(id,a,b,c) as (select stack(2 ,100,1,2,3 ,200,5,6,4))
select *, array_max(array(a,b,c)) as MaxOfColumns
from   t
```

| id | a | b | c | MaxOfColumns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 200 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 6 |